# Nuxt pages structure

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create urls in a specific structure by using nuxt pages such as:

parentfolder/about/name

Without having an index.vue file in the parent folder. My issue is if you navigate to the url without the sub folders the page is not found.

How in nuxt can you have a parent pages folder without an index file?

Comment: why don't you want to have an index file ? that's the way to do it

Comment: Because parent page is not actually a page. Client wants a specific url with that structure.

Comment: what do you want to happen when the user navigates to that url ?

Comment: Go to the specific url parent/about/name

Comment: so you want `/parent/` and `/parent/about/` to redirect to `/parent/about/name` ?

Comment: Yep. I know it’s strange and not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to redirect, then there are 2 ways to do that (that I can think of now)

you can place an `index.vue` in both the directories that redirects to the page you want like so

```html
<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ redirect }) {
    //redirects to the about page
    redirect(301, "/parent/about/name");
  },
};
</script>
```

and this will cause the page to get redirected immediately when the page is being loaded

Another option would be using a [`middleware`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware/) by creating a file in the `/middleware` directory in your project

so something like `middleware/redirect-to-name.js` (note it's a js file)

```js
export default function ({ redirect }) {
  return redirect("/parent/about/name");
}
```

and in every url you want to redirect, you can use this `index.vue` file

```html
<script>
export default {
  middleware: "post-auth",
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nuxt 3 latest feature: [`routeRules`](https://nitro.unjs.io/config/#routerules), to configure redirections from specific urls to others (like the parent url to child ones):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    '/parent': { redirect: '/parent/about/name' },
    '/parent/about': { redirect: '/parent/about/name' },
  }
})
```

Officially, it's still experimental but it works well.